# Signing a jnlp in order to get rid of the Security Warning

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet, jnlp, jar-signing

I am developing at a company where a jnlp file is used to start a swing web based java application. It has plenty of jars that are downloaded to the client's jvm cache. When I updated my jvm to its currently latest version (build 1.7.0_45-b18) I started seeing the security warning below when I try to run the jnlp file:

[image: Unknown publisher error]

After I saw this error and read this article about signing jnlp files from oracle site( [Signing JNLP files](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/signing_a_jnlp_file))
then I added three things to the project:

1. A **JNLP-INF** folder including an **APPLICATION.JNLP** file into all my jars except third party ones.
2. Signing all those jars with the digital certificate+keystore bundle of my own company
3. Importing the digital certificate into my trusted Ca certificates of jvm via java control panel.

After I did the changes above and tried to run the jnlp file after deployment of new jars I got the following Security warning message from jvm:

[image: known publisher but still jnlp not signed error]

As you can see the Security Warning's severity level is changed to a more welcoming level and now the publisher's name is not unknown.It is the name from the certificate. Even if the warning's level is decreased it is still a warning and I dont want my end users to see this everytime. How can I solve this problem?

1. Should I try to sign all third part jars as well? If so how can I do it with an Ant command? How can I extract a third party jar and add the JNLP-INF folder in it and then repack it as a jar by using Ant?
2. Should I also sign the final *myapplication*.ear file with a JNLP-INF subfolder in it.This ear file is deployed to jboss server?
3. Should I add some extra lines to my META-INF/MANIFEST  files in jars?
4. Should I be expecting oracle to block my application to run on jvm with this level of warning?

My JNLP file is this text:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://10.100.10.9/ikarusdelhitest/" href="ikarus.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Ikarus</title>
    <vendor>My Company name</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.mycompanyname.com" />
    <description>My jnlp triggered web based enterprise software</description>
    <icon href="ikarus.ico" />
    <offline-allowed />
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"
        java-vm-args="-Xnoclassgc -Xincgc -client -XX:DefaultMaxRAM=208M -Xms64M -Xmx256M -XX:PermSize=32M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=15 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=50" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ikarusClient.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ikarusDelegators.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/clientRules.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ruleImps.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ikarusUtil.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/ikarusResources.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/domain.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/domain_repository.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/domain_service.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/app_repository.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/app_service.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/infrastructure.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/ikarus/integration_domain.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jboss_ejb_auth/ejb3-persistence.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jboss_ejb_auth/jboss-ejb3x.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jboss_ejb_auth/jbossall-client.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/commons-digester-1.7.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/commons-logging-1.1.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/iText-2.1.0.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/jasperreports-3.6.0.jar" />
    <jar href="jars/jasper/poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar" />
    <property name="jnlp.localization" value="Delhi"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.celebi.ikarus.main.Ikarus" />
```

Thanks for any help/comment/brain storming.

Comment: So to just check.  All Jars, *including the 3rd part Jars,* are digitally signed with your company's certificate?  If not, it would explain the *"Part of the application is missing a digital signature"* message.

Comment: yes all the jars listed inside jnlp are signed. But only the non-thirdparty ones have JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP subfolder inside. Would this cause the problem?

Comment: AFAIU only the main Jar requires a signed JNLP.  BTW - Be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  By the way.  This JNLP seems to need signing because of `java-vm-args`  but realize that most of the memory related options can be specified in a way so that the JNLP does *not* need to be signed.  You might experiment with those instead, to see if it works for your app.

Comment: I dont have a main jar file that wraps the others. I am signing JNLP file as described here:[link](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/signing_a_jnlp_file) -  Is there any other way I can try to sign my jar?

Comment: *"I dont have a main jar file that wraps the others."*  Umm.. yeah OK.  That is pretty much what I had assumed from the Jar listing shown in the JNLP.  I also mentioned *"You might experiment with those instead, to see if it works for your app."*  Forgive my presumptions (if you feel like it), but when you come back with something like *"Is there any other way I can try to sign my jar?"* it seems you are ignoring me.  Since our communications are obviously failing for some reason, I doubt I can be of further help.  Sorry.

Comment: ignoring? I think i am misunderstood. I used Janela and the only remarkable thing it returned was _Resource type of ico of resource ikarus.ico is not one of the allowable types of gif,jpg,jpeg._  So i didnt mention any feedbacks from it. I deleted the java-vm-args part and resigned my all jars and then the security warning is gone.

Comment: *"I deleted the java-vm-args part and resigned my all jars and then the security warning is gone."*  OK, so even though the (original) question may not have been answered, the problem is solved?  (Your reply surprises me, enough so to resume trying to help.)

Comment: BTW - I don't know of any other way to sign Jars, but feel you are better off trying to get this way to work (or perhaps side-stepping the problem completely by removing the `java-vm-args`).

Comment: However now I am getting this start-time error stacktrace when I tried to run the warningless jnlp :

Comment: #### Java Web Start Error:
#### The Java security settings have prevented this application from running. You may change this behavior in the Java Control Panel.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.deploy.ui.DialogTemplate.imageAvailable(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.ui.DialogTemplate.finalImageAvailable(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.deploy.ui.ImageLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)

Comment: oracle is like a child who forgets about his toy and remembers it when some other child starts to like the toy. Even if the security warning issues are solved jvm still cries and gives errors :<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This JNLP seems to need signing because of `java-vm-args` but realize that most of the memory related options can be specified in a way so that the JNLP does *not* need to be signed.  I recommend you try that way instead.

**Edit**

JNLP was part of the Java Plug-In which was removed from browsers and deprecated by Oracle around Java 9. Use other methods to launch apps.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Thompson . That solved the Security warning and now the openin screen is [that](http://imageshack.com/a/img15/5433/2n9o.png)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are getting this warning because you are requesting the JNLP to run with full permissions, and the user needs to know about that.

If you application doesn't need to access critical resources (for instance write to the hard drive), you can run your application in sandbox mode by replacing the following:

```
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>
```

by

```
<security>
    <sandbox />
</security>
```

as documented in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html

You can also remove it as sandbox is the default value.

Comment: After removal of <security> part the application is blocked by default as it says in the documentation _If the Security Level slider in the Java Control Panel is set to Very High, the Permissions attribute is required. If it is not present, then the RIA is blocked._  Also when I change the <all-permissions /> to <sandbox />  nothing changes.

Comment: Then sorry, I was totally wrong :/ FYI I have a Java Web Start application for which I don't sign the JNLP and don't get this warning.

Comment: @alikerimerkan `Permissions` attribute is required in the jar manifest, it's not required in JNLP and defaults to `sandbox`. But the values in jar manifest and JNLP must be the same.