# JNLP signing is optional?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

It seems that JNLP signing is optional, but I cannot understand, why I get "jnlp not signed" warning at one time and not the other.

What are the conditions when JNLP signing is required?

Comment: related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481826/java-7u51-will-not-accept-jnlp-with-self-signed-certificate

Comment: I came to this question after reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947154/signing-a-jnlp-in-order-to-get-rid-of-the-security-warning

Answer (score 0):

Cannot tell for all cases, but looks like in mine it was triggered by "property" without "jnlp." prefix and/or extra parameter in "java-vm-args".

See details in
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources

> For an untrusted application, system properties set in the JNLP file will only be set by Java Web Start if they are considered secure.